# How to show two columns of names?

Tags: sql

SQL question

I have a table with Students (ID and Name)

I have another Table with Friends (ID1 and ID2)

```
create table Students(ID int, name text);
create table Friends(ID1 int, ID2 int);
```

If I enter:

```
SELECT Friends.ID1, Friends.ID2 FROM Friends
```

I get:

http://image.prntscr.com/image/d6e599ee5bd74c13822339afeb4c05ab.png

I think I need to use:

```
SELECT Strudets.Name 
from Friends, Strudents 
Where Strudents.ID=Friends.ID
```

And I want to show two columns of names

I need to look for the Friends.ID1 in the Students Table and get the Strudents.name, then do the same for Friends.ID2 and then show both names

**EDIT with more info**

When I enter this:

```html
SELECT id1, name
FROM friends
INNER JOIN students
ON friends.id1 = students.id
```

I get this:

[Lista de una sola columna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn53V.png)

And I need to show two columns of names

**ANSWER FROM @kbbal**

```html
SELECT s1.NAME, s2.NAME
FROM FRIENDS
INNER JOIN STUDENT s1 ON FRIENDS.ID1 = s1.ID
INNER JOIN STUDENT s2 ON FRIENDS.ID2 = s2.ID
```

I love this website!! <3

Comment: Where's your table structure?  How does Students link to Friends?  If ID1 and ID2 are friends, a Student can only have 2 friends maximum?  Please post necessary information if you want help.

Comment: Update the ticket with the type of DBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, etc.)

Comment: Please use the modern explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `where` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem new so I will lay out an approach.

1. Join the friends table to the students table. You should do this for the first friend first, so join the tables on the common ids. This would be the id column in the students table and id1 in the friends table.
2. Join the students table again. This time perform the join on id2 of the friends table
3. Specify that you want id1, name, id2, name in the SELECT statement

Your final answer should give you the ids of both friends and the names corresponding to their ids in the students table.

**Edit based on comments:**

Here is how you would do the joins:

```
SELECT friends.id1, s1.name, friends.id2, s2.name
FROM friends
INNER JOIN students s1
ON friends.id1 = s1.id
INNER JOIN students s2
ON friends id2 = s2.id
```

The trick is to actually join the students table twice, once for each friend. And then you just have to create aliases (s1 and s2) so you can distinguish between the two instances.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help but I really do not understand what you're telling me to do.
I was reading about http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp but I'm not really sure about how it works. This is my first time on this website.

Comment: Thank you very much, I put this in the pgAdmin and I get one column of names, I need two columns of names.

Comment: I'm trying:
SELECT id1, nombre, id2, nombre
FROM gusta
INNER JOIN estudiante ON gusta.id1 = estudiante.id
INNER JOIN estudiante ON gusta.id2 = estudiante.id
But I get an error :( - @kbball

Comment: necesitas s1, s2 porque hay dos JOIN

Comment: SELECT id1, s1.nombre, id2, s2.nombre FROM gusta INNER JOIN estudiante s1 ON gusta.id1 = s1.id INNER JOIN estudiante s2 ON gusta.id2 = s2.id

Comment: OMG!!! It worked!!! Thank you very much!! Did not know about the Alias tho. Thank you!! @kbball

Comment: Hey, **THANK YOU** very much for taking the time to help me... I'm sorry that it took me too long to understand, I'm new at this! Thaanks from Cartagena, Colombia!! @kbball